# How can I add autoload_paths in my Rails4 Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Usually I add the following in config/application.rb to add autload_paths:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'poros', '{**}')]
```

How can I achieve the same in an engine?
It seems to work when I just use the same code in application.rb in the host app, however I think it's ugly that the code is not in the engine and needs to be added to the host app to make things work.

The only solution I found to add the load path through the engine is by adding this to lib/engine/engine.rb:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Dir.glob(Rails.root + "../../app/poros/**/*.rb").each do |c|
    require_dependency(c)
  end
end
```

However there seems to be something fundamentally wrong with this as this leads to problems when I'm doing console reloads (e.g. it tells me that constants are already defined or that concerns can't execute the include block twice)

What is the right way to do this in the engine itself? (can't believe this is so hard/uncommon, I have really googled a lot but I can't find a solution)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Rails::Engine documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html), you can add autoload paths in your Railtie like this:

```
class MyEngine < Rails::Engine
  # Add a load path for this specific Engine
  config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../lib/some/path", __FILE__)

  initializer "my_engine.add_middleware" do |app|
    app.middleware.use MyEngine::Middleware
  end
end
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. E.g. in rails console I'm getting 'uninitialized constant' errors, my classes aren't loading

Comment: Does your engine use `isolate_namespace` in its Railtie? If yes, do you try to call the classes with the appropriate namespace, i.e. `EngineName::Class`?

Comment: I don't use isolated namespace, I created the engine with --full (not --mountable).
I have tried all of the following according to doc:
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'poros', '{**}')]
config.autoload_paths += Dir.glob(File.expand_path("../../app/poros/") + "**/*.rb")
config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../../app/poros/test.rb")
config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../../app/poros", __FILE__)

Comment: An engines default directories such as 'app/models' should be loaded automatically; what directory is the missing class in? Is the class namespaced somehow? EDIT - when you call `Rails.root.join` inside the engine, is that the root of the engine or of the host app?

Comment: I created the folder /app/poros/ and that's where a lot of classes are located. There shouldn't be any namespace at all. With the config.to_prepare code in my OP everything is working just fine, except it's yielding errors when I reload the console. I really appreciate your input thank you

Comment: Could you try `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/poros)` ?

Comment: Rails.root is yielding nil when called in lib/test_engine/engine.rb directly.
Rails.root.join is working when I wrap it in config.to_prepare block and it's the root of the engine of the host app. I tried config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/poros) and I'm getting NameError: uninitialized constant TestClass when loading the console

Comment: Sorry, I just tried it in one of my engines, and it works flawlessly. `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/app/poros)`, with `app/poros/test_class.rb` defining `TestClass`.

Comment: Oh, it was my bad! My classes were actually in deeper folder structures in app/poros, e.g. app/poros/worker/. Your solution works perfectly as long as the classes are in app/poros.
So basically, now I'm using `config.autoload_paths += Dir[config.root.join('app', 'poros', '{**}')]` and it's working perfectly with all subfolders! Thank you very much for elaborating you were really helpful

Comment: I am using isolate namespace. and subdirectories in my engines models. `config.autoload_paths += Dir[config.root.join('app', 'models', 'my_engine_name', '{**}')]` in `engines/my_engine_name/lib/my_engine_name/engine.rb` almost worked. I got a problem with `LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Person, expected /home/blah/blah/registration/engines/my_engine_name/app/models/my_engine_name/people/person.rb to define it` so my directory structure was not right. I had `/models/my_engine_name/people/person.rb` but it needs to be `/models/my_engine_name/people/my_engine_name/person.rb`

Comment: what is the `add_middleware` initializer doing? I'm trying to add subdirectories of my engine's models directory, not trying to do anything with middleware.

Comment: @FredWillmore pretty much what it says on the tin - it adds a middleware to the stack. That code example from the Rails documentation covers more than one aspect of Railties; if all you want to do is change the load paths, you can leave it out.

Answer (score 2):

If `poros` is a subdirectory of app, you do not need add it again.

> All subdirectories of app in the application and engines present at boot time. For example, app/controllers. They do not need to be the default ones, any custom directories like app/workers belong automatically to autoload_paths.